# Model for headphone quality as a function of price

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis, logistic-regression

I've looked for any mathematical model that shows headphone quality as a function of the price of the headphones, but have not found anything yet. Of course, "quality" is quite subjective, which could be a reason I'm not finding much, but from my research (i.e. Google) it seems that it's pretty much accepted that initially, as more money is invested in a pair of headphones, the quality begins to increase fairly rapidly, and then around $150 is the point of diminishing returns.

My goal is to find this point of diminishing returns by finding the second derivative of the function and solving for zero, which would give me the inflection point, or the point of diminishing returns.

My guess would be a logistics growth model of the form $$f(x) = \frac{a}{1+b e^{-k x}},  k>0$$ where $a$ is the maximum quality and $\frac{a}{1+b}$ is the inital value for a pair of headphones costing $0.

The function would probably need to be adjusted where I set a pair of headphones costing $c$ dollars would give evaluate to $f(c) = 1$ and then $f(x)$ would give the quality as more of a "percentage" of quality compared to the one costing $c$ dollars. I could also start by setting $150 as the point of diminishing returns, which would mean

$$f''(150)=0$$

The problem with that is I want to find what the point of diminishing returns is, so this doesn't really address my motivation for doing this.

I don't have any data that I have found to try doing logistic regression, and I am not too knowledgeable in regards to headphone quality. Ideally someone else has already modeled this so I can use that as a starting point.

Comment: Usually the first step in data fitting is collecting the data.  You need a bunch of headphone rankings (wherever they come from) paired with price.Then plot it and see what the curve looks like.  Now you can think about functional forms.

Comment: As @RossMillikan states, you need to have data. How else are you going to measure the accuracy of your model?

Comment: @Mika'il it seemed worse that that to me, like OP wants to formulate a model before looking at any data.  A silly possibility would be that you can build headphones that sell for a few or a few tens of dollars, but there is a magic chip that vastly improves the quality and you can only afford at a price point of 100 dollars.  There will be a big step in quality at that price and no logistic curve will fit well.  The sum of two might fit well, though.  That is why one should look at the data.

Comment: I'm fully capable of taking data and forming a model from it, but was hoping someone already developed a model. I wasn't planning on spending a ton of time with this, as it's just a simple curiosity of where the point of diminishing returns is from a mathematical standpoint. I do not have terribly strong data mining skills nor do I have much knowledge in acoustics and audiology, so I'm not entirely sure what type of model would fit best. My guess was a function that increased quickly and then changed concavity and leveled off, which led me to a logistic model.